# Automatically scroll to a position in an Adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, baseadapter

I am trying to get my program to automatically scroll to the integer position set by the global integer AtlasApplication.sSelectedPositionForLaw. I have tried using mNotificationLv.smoothScrollToPostion(AtlasApplication.sSelectedPositionForLaw) with no luck in SubMenuActivity. How can I make SubMenuActivity automatically scroll to the selected position in the adapter?

SubMenuActivity

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    try {
        super.onResume();
        FontLoader.loadFonts(this);
        headerLayout.LoadHeaderFont();
        footerLayout.LoadFooterFont();
        FontLoader.setRalewayBoldFont(mSubMenuHeaderTv);
        FontLoader.setAwesomeFont(mSubMenuBackTv);
        FontLoader.setAtlasFont(mSubMenuIconTv);
        loadSubMenuLabel();
        subMenuAdapter.setList(AtlasApplication.lstLawsForLocation);
        mNotificationLv.setAdapter(subMenuAdapter);
        mNotificationLv.smoothScrollToPosition(21);

        activityResumed();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        exceptionHandler.handle(e, "onResume()");
    }
}
```

SubMenuAdapter

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_sub_menu_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.rowSubMenuLl = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_sub_menu_ll);
        holder.mSubMenuTitleTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sub_menu_title_tv);
        holder.mSubMenuDetailPane = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sub_menu_detail_pane_ll);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    FontLoader.setRalewayRegularFont(holder.mSubMenuTitleTv);

    LawModel notificationModel = lstSubMenuModels.get(position);

    if(Integer.parseInt(notificationModel.getTagID()) == AtlasApplication.sSelectedPositionForLaw) {
        notificationModel.setSelected(true);
    }

    holder.mSubMenuTitleTv.setText(notificationModel.getTagName().trim());

    if (notificationModel.isSelected) {
        //AtlasApplication.SubMenuTitle = notificationModel.getTagName();
        AtlasApplication.sLawModelSelected = notificationModel;
        AtlasApplication.sSelectedPositionForLaw=position;
        if (holder.mSubMenuDetailPane.getChildCount() < 1) {
            SpeedingFines sf = new SpeedingFines(context, holder.mSubMenuDetailPane);
            sf.setPriorityListener(mOnPriorityUpdateListener);

            holder.rowSubMenuLl.setBackgroundResource(R.color.taxes_bg);
            holder.mSubMenuDetailPane.requestFocus();
        }
    } else {
        holder.mSubMenuDetailPane.removeAllViews();
        holder.rowSubMenuLl.setBackgroundResource(R.color.grad_dark);
    }

    holder.mSubMenuTitleTv.setId(position);
    holder.mSubMenuTitleTv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setAllselectedFalse(v.getId());
            lstSubMenuModels.get(v.getId()).isSelected = !lstSubMenuModels.get(v.getId()).isSelected;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}

private void setAllselectedFalse(int selectedRow) {
    AtlasApplication.sSelectedPositionForLaw=-1;
    for (int i = 0; i < lstSubMenuModels.size(); i++) {
        if (i != selectedRow) {
            lstSubMenuModels.get(i).setSelected(false);
        }
    }
}

public void setList(List<LawModel> subMenuModels) {
    this.lstSubMenuModels = subMenuModels;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView mSubMenuTitleTv;
    LinearLayout rowSubMenuLl, mSubMenuDetailPane;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time ago i was doing something like that, i could scroll to a custom position in this way:

```
    listView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            listView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
        }
    });
```

So, in your case it can be:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
try {
    super.onResume();
    FontLoader.loadFonts(this);
    headerLayout.LoadHeaderFont();
    footerLayout.LoadFooterFont();
    FontLoader.setRalewayBoldFont(mSubMenuHeaderTv);
    FontLoader.setAwesomeFont(mSubMenuBackTv);
    FontLoader.setAtlasFont(mSubMenuIconTv);
    loadSubMenuLabel();
    subMenuAdapter.setList(AtlasApplication.lstLawsForLocation);
    mNotificationLv.setAdapter(subMenuAdapter);
    mNotificationLv.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mNotificationLv.smoothScrollToPosition(21);
        }
    });

    activityResumed();
}
catch(Exception e){
    exceptionHandler.handle(e, "onResume()");
}
```

}

**The reason i think is**:

> the  UI(user interface) of android work based on a queue of things to
>   do, and making in a runnable post function you are telling the UI,
>   when it can, after it has done all things in queue  perform some
>   actions, in this case to scroll to certain position of listView.

Answer (score -1):

I am here to solve your problem:

calculate the number of views to get to the right position and with almost you can get to your position:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < mListView.getChildCount(); i++) {
    if(sum > position){
        mListView.smoothScrollToPosition(i);
        break;
    }
    sum = sum + mListView.getChildAt(i).getHeight();
}
```

Good LUCk ...

Comment: I have the right position. I need to figure out how to make the screen automatically scroll....